# Select Pseudo-element (such ::before and ::after ) of element in DOM

Tags: html, css, dom

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="class"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.class:before {
   content: "text";
   color: red;
}
```

I need to change the red colour to green in DOM (no jQuery)

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: Hello :)
May I ask you if there is a reason for you to use pseudo elements (`::before`)? You could simply stile your text the normal way I believe.

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333

Answer (score 0):

yes, with css variables

```js
const Root = document.documentElement;

Root.style.setProperty('--mycolor', 'green');
```

```css
:root {
  --mycolor : red;
}
.class:before {
  content: "text";
  color: var(--mycolor);
}
```

```html
<div class="class"></div>
```